# Псевдографический интерфейс в QBasic

Tags: gui, qbasic

Подскажите, пожалуйста, готовый модуль для создания пользовательского интерфейса на псевдографике в QBasic (for MSDOS).
Не хочется писать велосипед, а запрос Google что-то не могу придумать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TUI оно называлось. Соответственно, гугление надо вести на что-то в духе «"QuickBasic" TUI window»

http://www.angelfire.com/d20/quickbasic/LIB/ — как минимум, в BASWIN21.ZIP, на первый взгляд, что-то похожее на то, что надо.

Comment: Спасибо. Буду смотреть в новом, 2013 году

Comment: Еще раз спасибо- в ссылке самое оно.